# Why double slash comments in double-quoted PHP echo string generates JS error?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So ... That I have a strange style of coding - it's true ( see the example ), but why JS generates error when I use double slash comments, instead of multi-line /* */ comments.

This is my PHP code with JS function in it. It is just (not)working example. You can try it with copy and paste:

```
<?php
echo "<script>";
echo "function OnTxtChange( ) {";
echo "  var i = parseInt((document.getElementsByName('inp'))[0].value);";
echo " // Increment input with 1";
echo "  document.getElementsByName('out').item(0).innerHTML = ++i;";
echo "}";
echo "</script>";
echo "<input style='width:3em;' type='number' value=1 name='inp' onchange='OnTxtChange( )'>";
echo "<p name='out'>2</p>";
?>
```

Double slash comment in double-quoted string:

```
echo " // Increment input with 1";
```

generates JS error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

When I use multi-line /* */ comment, there is not error:

```
echo " /* Increment input with 1*/";
```

Why ?

Comment: You're not echoing line break characters so it's all in one line as far as JavaScript is concerned.

Comment: Try to look at the actual output generated by this…!?

Comment: Stop using PHP to generate Javascript, *especially* if you aren't even including any PHP variables. Break out of PHP entirely, or just include a separate static JS file.

Comment: I tried with '<br>' - it does not work. Anyway, with a '\n' works!
I will use multi-line comments.
iainn, this is only short example, thank you!
Thank you, all!

Comment: I agree, why bother using echo in the first place? Just write out plain JavaScript outside the PHP block, especially since you're not even using any PHP variables in it. Then you won't have even the potential for this kind of problem, and the code will be much easier to read, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments using the

```
//
```

operator need to be in a separate line. You did not use line breaks, hence after the first appearance of such a comment, everything else will be commented, not ending the functions. You will need to use line breaks of

```
\n
```

to break the lines and get the expected code.